# How do I avoid using arrays?

Tags: c++

My professor wants us to write a program without using arrays or vectors like this:

> Write a program using functions that calculates and prints parking charges for each of the n customers who parked their cars in the garage.
>
> Parking rates:
>
> - a parking garage charges a $5.00 minimum fee to park for up to five hours.
> - the garage charges an additional $0.50 per hour for each hour or part thereof in the excess of five hours
> - the maximum charge for any given 24hr period is $10.00. Assume that no car parks longer that 24 hours at a time.
>
> You should enter the hours parked for each customer. Your program should print the results in a neat tabular format and should calculate and print the total of your receipts.
>
> The program output should look like this:
>
> ```
> car------Hours------Charge
>
> 1--------2.00--------$5.00 
>
> 2--------5.00--------$5.00
>
> 3--------5.30--------$5.50
>
> etc.
>
> total: 3---12.30----$15.50
> ```

I only managed to get this far:

```
include <iostream>
include <conio.h>
include <cmath>
include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
double calculate(double);
int main()
{
    double hours,charge;
    int finish;
    double sumhours;
    sumhours=0;
    finish=0;
    charge=0;
    int cars;
    cars=0;

    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter the number of hours the vehicle has been parked: "<<endl;
        cin>>hours;
        cars++;
        sumhours+=hours;
        finish=cin.get();
        if(hours>24)
        {
            cout<<"enter a time below 24hrs."<<endl;
            cars--; 
            sumhours=sumhours-hours;
        }
    }
        while(finish!=EOF);

        double total=calculate(hours);
        cout<<total<<": "<<(cars-1)<<": "<<sumhours;


    while(!_kbhit());
    return 0;
}

double calculate(double time)
{
    double calculate=0;
    double fees;

    if(time<=5)
        return 5;
     if(time>15)
        return 10;

     time=ceil(time);
     fees=5+(.5*(time-5));

    return calculate;

}
```

Comment: And what are the problems that you are facing? SO is not a private tutor; we help with _specific_ code problems here.

Comment: What is the specific question here?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know where to store the data, because we can't use arrays.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a file?

Comment: You don't have to store data. Store the output

Comment: Is building up the output text into a `std::stringstream` considered cheating?

Comment: Perhaps you're supposed to use a linked list instead. What are you learning about in class right now?

Comment: Sounds like your instructor wants to you learn to use Standard Library "lists" :)    http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/stllist.html

Comment: **What are you learning in class, right now????** Answer that, or we can't help.

Comment: we have gone over control structures and functions

Comment: @John: Ask your instructor or query the Web for "summing variables" or "running total" variables. See my response below.  By the way, there is no need to store the data.

Comment: @Thomas doesn't address the tabular output. You cannot have that tabular output unless you stream separately, output in reverse (recursive) or you have data saved off.

Comment: @Xadde:  You can have tabular output by using a fixed field width, say 30 characters (to be extreme).  See `std::setw` in the `iomanip` header file.  Also, research the term "K.I.S.S.".  Don't add unnessary or unspecified complications.

Comment: @Thomas Xaade's issue is that the data the user types in the console will be in the middle of the result table, unless they're buffered.  He's right, unless cin/cout are redirected (unlikely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every iteration, generate the relevant output, but don't stream it to `std::cout`.  Instead, stream it to a [`std::stringstream`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) object.  Then, at the end, stream that object to `std::cout`.  The maths can be done simply by maintaining a running accumulation of the input values.

This, of course, assumes that using a `std::stringstream` is not considered "cheating" in the context of this homework exercise.

Comment: The hell it doesn't. It allows you to build up output without outputting immediately. Then you just keep a current sum only. I think **this is THE answer**.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: AFAICS, it exactly addresses the OP's concern.

Comment: @Mooing Duck There are two problems. Problem 1 is outputting each item in tabular format after all input is done. Problem 2 is outputting the sum. The sum is answered by a running accumulation (which is mentioned in this answer). The tabular output is handled by delaying output with a separate stream. This answers both problems. The competing answers only address the sum or suggest an input file. Neither helps.

Comment: Removed my comments, I failed to think how std::cin and std::cout interact.  My bad.

Comment: I didn't catch that he in fact said "print". If he's printing then you don't have to avoid the input/output issue.

Comment: This worked but we haven't gone over this in class yet. regardless, thank you.

Comment: **Very important note:** This works unless the professor expects you to print to a file, which you mentioned. Instead of streaming output back to cout, stream out to a file. If the professor meant print to console, this is *the ONLY way* to satisfy the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework, here is an algorithm:
1. Print header.
2.  Clear *running total* variables.
3.  While not end of file
3.1    read a record.
3.2    print record contents
3.3    **add record field values to *running total* variables**  (Hint! Hint!)
3.4.   end-while
4.  print out *running total* variables.

You may have to do some additional calculations with the *running total* variables, especially for averages.

**Edit 1: Example of a running total variable**

```
int sum = 0; // This is the running total variable.
const unsigned int QUANTITY = 23;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < QUANTITY; ++i)
{
    cout << "Adding " << i << " to sum.\n";
    sum += i;
}
cout << "Sum is: " << sum << "\n";
cout.flush();
```

In this example, the data 'i' is not stored only used.  The `sum` variable is a running total.
Look for similarities in your assignment.

**Edit 2:  Example of detecting end of input on cin**

```
char reply = 'n';
while (tolower(reply) != 'y')
{
   cout << "Do you want to quit? (y/n)";
   cout.flush();
   cin >> reply;
   cin.ignore(1000, '\n'); // Eat up newline.
}
cout << "Thanks for the answer.\n";
cout.flush();
```

Comment: +1 for not suggesting something that behaves like an array to begin with

Comment: what can I store the record in? since the record is supposed to be infinitely expanding.

Comment: -1 A file is a possible solution, but the student hasn't covered any files yet. @oli and mine are mostly likely correct.

Comment: The problem is that the user needs to input all the hours and the program then prints out the charges after the user is done.

Comment: @Xaade: Thomas reads until he reaches EOF, just like the OP did.  I'd assume that means the user will manually enter whatever value EOF is.  No files involved.

Comment: @John: THINK.  Is the summation example I posted printing out all the values, then prints out the sum (addition of all the numbers) at the end?  Hmmmmmmmm.  "Minds are like parachutes, best work when open."

Comment: @Xaade:  THINK, OUTSIDE THE BUN. The same algorithm will work with `cin` as well.  The challenge for the O.P. is translating *end of file* to *end of input*.  I'm really glad you people are not working for me!

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: the user input would appear in the middle of your table if the user uses cin

Comment: Well, it appears as if he's allowed to print out to a file. This reduces the complexity tremendously, which makes your answer correct. However, in your last comment you are wrong. There's no way to output to the same stream a finalized table of all input, while taking input in the same stream, without storing values in an array. However, you can stream to a separate stream (in our case, a file).

Comment: I cannot output to a file and the problem was never summation.

Comment: @John:  Give me a break, no summation, then what is "print the *total* of your receipts"?  None of my examples state to print to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't use arrays or vectors, I think you should print the parking data for each car as it's being processed. Pseudocode:

```
While more cars:
    Read data for next car
    Calculate cost
    Print data
    Add to running totals
End while
Print totals
```

Comment: Are you talking about the fact that if it's using stdin and stdout from the console, then the input lines and the output lines will be interleaved? Then nothing can be done about that. Also, the original poster did not specify any additional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try storing your values in a linked list structure instead of an array. Linked lists work great for dynamic storage.
Try this tutorial, http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson15.html

Comment: This is a nice solution if the O.P. has learned about lists.  Usually, this assignment is given out to use *summing* or *running total* variables.

Comment: One of my instructors was a data structure freak, linked lists was the first thing that popped into my head. But your right, the he should be thinking about what his instructor is looking for in the assignment

Comment: -1 This is just a technicality. It's obvious the instructor wants to avoid any sort of data storage mechanism.

Comment: Hey, why the down vote? Its not obvious, the OP just said he can't use arrays. I'm not psychic.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion then is to use a recursive method, the method first accepts input, asks if there is any more input. If there is more input, it then calls itself. If there is no more input, it outputs it's current car and then returns a sum that's added so far in a structure.

The only problem with this method is that it would output entered cars in reverse of input, but it would do so without an array or a file to save to.

Comment: @Downvoter: How does this not fulfill the requirements listed in the question?

Comment: What happens when someone wants to do 20 million records?  Unless your compiler does TCO, your program won't be able to handle it.  And even if it does, recursion won't solve any problem that a `while` loop can't, and makes some things more complicated.

Comment: @Mooing Duck You have yet to address the tabular output. Not addressing the tabular output which is supposed to occur after all input is an incomplete answer.

Comment: @cHao Any possible answer to this question that doesn't involve saving input to a file or saving output to a file would have the same problems. I hardly expect a student just now being taught control structures would have been taught or expected to know about fileIO.

Comment: I would.  A stream's a stream.  If they can output to a console, or read from one, then they can do the same from/to a file (or a string stream, for that matter).

Comment: I apologize, apparently I overlooked the fact that the OP does mention "print"ing output. Tabular output isn't an issue, since you can stream out to the file while you're taking input.